# Docker Sdk for python mount error on trying to start service

Tags: python, docker

I am trying to replicate a service in a swarm using Docker Sdk For Python that I have working whilst using docker-compose.

The docker-compose part I'm trying to replicate is the following:

```
docker-master:
        image: locustio/locust
        ports:
         - "8089:8089"
        volumes:
          - ./:/mnt/locust
        command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py --master -H http://master:8089
```

And what I have written in my python script to try to replicate this is:

```
loadgenerator = client.services.create(
        image='locustio/locust',
        name='loadgenerator',
        endpoint_spec=docker.types.EndpointSpec(ports = [{
            "Name": "locust",
            "Protocol": "tcp",
            "PublishedPort": 8089,
            "TargetPort": 8089
        }]),
        mounts=('/','/mnt/locust/','rw'),
        networks=[bridge_network.id],
        command='-f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py -H http://10.0.2.15:8080',
        maxreplicas=1
    )
```

I've tried every possible path I can think of to try get this to work but I either receive an error either telling me that it won't accept a relative path, or that the command could not find the file needed afterward.

Don't suppose anybody has dealt with a problem like this before? All my other mounts in that python script are working perfectly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're trying to mount the filesystem root `/` instead of the directory where your docker-compose.yaml is located `./`

Comment: So I’ve tried to give an a absolute path from /home/ to the directory, but still giving an error. Thank you for reply